# How to return a pointer to a full array a.k.a int(*)[] to the main function

Tags: c, pointers, memory

My functions purpose is to make a 2d array of integers on the heap. After I create the pointer to a whole array I return the pointer to the whole array to a void*. I feel like there is a better return type but I can't seem to get the write syntax.

Please let me know if I can do a better return type rather than just a void*.

```
void* create_matrix(int x, int y){
    int i, j, count;
    int(*matrix)[x] = calloc(y, sizeof *matrix); // a pointer to a full array of size x.
    //matrix = address of array
    //*matrix = address of first element of array; *(matrix + 1) = address of first element of second array
    //**matrix = element that exists at the first element of array; *(*(matrix + 1) + 1) = second element of second array = matrix[1][1]
    count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < y; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < x; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = ++count;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < y; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < x; j++){
            printf("%d\n", matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: The full type depends on `x`, which varies depending on how it's called, so you can't declare that as the type.

Comment: Hayden Labrie, Perhaps `bool create_matrix(int x, int y, int (*matrix)[y][x])` (Uses VLA support) and have the caller pass in the location to save the pointer. Return a flag for allocation success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a pointer to an array of unspecified size:

```
int (*create_matrix(int x, int y))[]
{
   ...
}
```

Which will be compatible with a pointer to a VLA:

```
int (*a)[x]=create_matrix(x,y);
```

The array types are compatible because the size is not a constant in both places.  This is specified in section 6.7.6.2p6 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible
> element types, and if both size specifiers are present, and are
> integer constant expressions, then both size specifiers shall have the
> same constant value. If the two array types are used in a context
> which requires them to be compatible, it is undefined behavior if the
> two size specifiers evaluate to unequal values

Comment: Thank you! I did not know the correct syntax to return a pointer to a whole array that holds ints. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @HaydenLabrie, consider using `typeof` extension (a feature in C23) to make the declaration of return type a bit easier to read. `typeof(int[])* create_matrix(int x,int y)`

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do better if you don't *return* the pointer from the function, but pass its to the function by reference (i.e. pass its address) and initialise it there. For example

```
void alloc_matrix(int x, int y, int (**pmat)[x])
{
  int (*matrix)[x] = calloc(...);
  ...;
  *pmat = matrix;
}

...
int x = 5;
int y = 6;
int (*matrix)[x]; // important, declare matrix when x is already known
alloc_matrix(x, y, &matrix);
```

---

You can also incorporate both dimensions into the matrix type if you want, i.e. `int (*matrix)[x][y]`. But then you will need to write `(*matrix)[i][j]` instead of `matrix[i][j]` which is a bit inconvenient. Although nominally there is one extra level of indirection, both variants should produce the exact same machine code.